# Error: operator and operand do not agree with trees

Tags: compiler-errors, sml

I've been trying to make a function that takes an int arbol1, being:

```
datatype ’a arbol1 = Nodo of ’a * ’a arbol1 list
```

Here is an example of this tree:

```
Nodo(1, [Nodo(2, [Nodo(6, []), Nodo(3, [])]), Nodo(1, [])])
```

And it has to duplicate the int variable of each node, this is the code I managed to write but it isn't working and I can't figure out why, here it is:

```
fun dobleArbol1 (Nodo(x, [])) = Nodo(x * 2, [])
  | dobleArbol1 (Nodo(x, t :: ts) : int arbol1) = 
      Nodo(x * 2, dobleArbol1(t) :: dobleArbol1(hd(ts)));
```

The compiler is giving me this error:

```
stdIn:151.50-151.91 Error: operator and operand do not agree [tycon mismatch]
  operator domain: int arbol1 * int arbol1 list
  operand:         int arbol1 * int arbol1
  in expression:
    dobleArbol1 t :: dobleArbol1 (hd ts)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're overthinking it.

A node in your tree has a value, and a list (possibly empty) of trees.

To map a function to every value in any node, you need to apply that function to the value, and then map it across the list of trees.

A very simple list map looks like:

```
fun listMap(f, []) = []
  | listMap(f, x::xs) = f x :: listMap(f, xs)
```

Now a tree map function:

```
fun treeMap(f, Nodo(x, lst)) =
  Nodo(f x, listMap((fn t => treeMap(f, t)), lst))
```

And then doubling every value in the tree is just an application of `treeMap`.

```
fun doubleTree(t) = treeMap((fn x => x * 2), t)
```

If we wanted, we could multiply every number in a tree by 2, add 1, the divide by 3 very easily:

```
treeMap((fn x => (x * 2 + 1) / 3), t)
```

When you break big problems down, they become easier.

As for your specific error:

```
dobleArbol1(t) :: dobleArbol1(hd(ts))
```

We know you want `dobleArbol1` to map a tree to a tree. But the righthand operand to `::` must be a list.

We can see this in action by trying a much simpler function:

```
fun f x = x :: x
```